# same $.ajax call is ASYNC in Chrome but SYNC in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dumb simple ajax call to a nonexistent url with an error callback:

```
$.ajax("non-nonexistent-url", {
    error: function () {
        alert("FOO");
    }
});
alert("BAR");
```

When I run it in Chrome, I get "BAR" then "FOO" alerts, which is the behavior I expect - ajax call is asynchronous.
In IE, however, I get "FOO" then "BAR", which looks like synchronous call, but why? It should be async by default, right?
I hoped it's guaranteed that `$.ajax` returns before any callbacks are executed...

Comment: This reproduces the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KDAGI tested in IE10

Comment: One work-around would be to use .fail instead of the inline error option, though that of course isn't an answer to why this happens.

Comment: Another workaround would be `setTimeout(function(){/* something */}, 0);`

Comment: IE 11 is "BAR" "FOO".

Comment: If it's "asynchronous" why are you relying on an execution order?

Comment: @Jasen I'm using Backbone which "relies" on it. This is Backbone's source code:


`var xhr = options.xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));

model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);`


They want to trigger "request" event when a model has started a request to the server, but in IE I actually get "error" event first and only then "request" event, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assumption on the reason :

If the host in the URL does not exist, no request is actually made. While in IE only the request is asynchronous, in other browsers the host lookup is also asynchronous.

Comment: looks, like this's exactly what's happening, thanks!